# How do we understand the Iterator for a set<pair<int,int>>?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

So I have declared a set which will hold a pair of integers.
What is `temp` ? Does it mean that `temp` will point to a `pair<int,int>` ?

```
set<pair<int, int>> myset;
pair<int, int> temp = *(myset.begin());
```

How is the code below different from the code above? Can I please have a definition of what exactly these codes are doing.

```
pair<int, int>::iterator temp;
temp = *(myset.begin());
```

Comment: Do both of these code snippets compile?

Comment: The difference is that second code snippet will not compile.

Comment: A `std::set<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator` is something that dereferences to a reference to a `std::pair<int, int>` if a valid iterator, and has undefined behavior if not a valid iterator (such as `myset.end()`).

Comment: I didn't test if the second code complies. I want to know how is the second code different from the first one.

Comment: Test if the second code compiles and you'll have your answer as to how they differ.

Comment: Oh, the second one does not compile. Ok, so temp is an iterator in the second piece of code. Whereas in the first piece of code temp is a pair<int, int> ready to receive the dereferenced pair from the *(myset.begin())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
set<pair<int, int>> myset;
pair<int, int> temp = *(myset.begin());
```

the variable `temp` is a `pair`, holding two `int`'s.

`myset.begin()` returns an iterator, pointing to the first element in the `set` of `pair`'s named `myset`. It gets dereferenced by `*` and the value  (the `pair`) gets copied into `temp`.

In this code:

```
pair<int, int>::iterator temp;
temp = *(myset.begin());
```

the variable `temp` is first declared as an iterator for a `pair<int, int>` and then the code tries to copy the value of a `pair<int, int>` into it. This will not compile.

Comment: *"the variable temp is first initialised "* it is not initialized. It is declared.

Answer (score 1):

At the second example you are trying to assign a `std::pair<int, int>` to an iterator. This does not work, as iterators only point at data, and do not own the data.

```
pair<int, int>::
iterator temp = *(myset.begin());
//                     ^ gives iterator at the start of set, pointing to first el.
//              ^ dereferences iterator, gives `std::pair<int, int>&`
//            ^ `std::pair<int, int> is assigned to non-reference, and therefore 
//               forced to copy.
//  ^ temp is an iterator to an element (iterators don't own elements, 
//               only point to them). You can't initialize an iterator with data.
```